# Iterating a vector over a list in R

Tags: r, list, iteration, montecarlo

I am dealing with some computational feature extracting problem from RNA data, and I found myself unable to deal with this question:

I have n sequences (say two for example) from which I obtained an iterated statistic i times (kind of doing a Monte Carlo iteration for analizing distribution of obtained statistics compared with original).

Example:

Say we iterate 10 times

```
n <- 10
```

I got a vector of 20 values with all the iterations, but this vector corresponds to two different sequences, so I must divide this vector in two equal parts (the iterations are ordered 1:10 - 1:10 for each sequence).

```
MFEit <- c(10, 12, 34, 32, 12 .....)  ## vector of length 20
MFEit.split <- split(MFEit, ceiling(MFEit.along/n5))
```

This generates a list of two items each with 10 values, named $`1` and $`2`

On the other hand I have a vector of two values which are the original statistics, each corresponding to each original sequence

```
MFE <- c(25, 15)
```

What I want to do is to know how many values of first item in the list MFEit.split, are equal or less than the first value of MFE, and, iteratively, how many values of second item in the list MFEit.split, are equal or less than the second value of MFE, and so on, provided that I would have more than two values or items.

I know how to do it one by one, say:

```
R <- length(subset(MFEit.split$`1`, MFEit.split$`1`<=MFE[1]))
R <- length(subset(MFEit.split$`2`, MFEit.split$`1`<=MFE[2]))
```

But... how to include this into a loop so that I can get iteratively each comparison, no matter how many MFE values or items in the list I have?

The desired output would be a vector called R, with n values corresponding to each comparison.

Any help?...

Comment: `sapply(Map(\`<=\`, MFEit.split, MFE), sum)` ?

Comment: Wow, it worked like Magic ! ! ! Many thanks. Did not know about the Map function.